# How do I access class variables from an event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I'm using the prototype javascript libraries. My code is below.  I've created a class and in that class I have created an event listener for one of the class methods.  In that method I need to access both the attributes of the form element that triggers the event and the class properties.  Currently, the code understands $(this).getValue() in the event because this is being assigned to the form element that triggered the event.  How can I access the this.makingRequest and this.user properties from the event function?  Can I pass them in as parameters somehow?  If so, how?  Nothing I've tried to this point works.  Thanks for any help.

```
function AddressBookEntryObj(user, selectField)
{
    this.selectField = selectField;
    this.user = user;
    this.makingRequest = false;
    this.debugMode = false;

    Event.observe(this.selectField, 'change', handleEvent);
}

//Prototype statements
AddressBookEntryObj.prototype.handleEvent = handleEvent;
//End prototype statements

function handleEvent()
{
    try
    {
        if (!this.makingRequest) 
        {
            this.makingRequest = true;    
            var ajax = 
                new Ajax.Request(
                    '/servlet/MyReallyCoolServlet',
                    {
                        method:     'get', 
                        parameters:    { 
                            action:         'doGet', 
                             whichFunc:         'MyReallyCoolFunction',
                             fieldValue:     $(this).getValue(),
                             user:            this.user
                         }, 
                        onCreate:    handleAjaxCreate,
                        onComplete: handleChangeComplete 
                    }
                );
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        alert("handleEvent Error: \r\n" + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nH3ew/)

Take a look at this jsfiddle I made with your code. You needed to add "bind(this)" to your callback handler. Doing that will make "this" be your object and use "e.target" to access the html element.

_Michael

Comment: Thanks, man.  I had tried that before but had obviously screwed something up.  I appreciate the help.  jsfiddle is pretty cool, btw.

Comment: No problem and yeah JSFiddle rocks, it's my goto tool when I need to trouble shoot something with the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use:

```
AddressBookEntryObj.prototype.handleEvent = function()
{
}
```

Then `this` inside handleEvent should point to `AddressBookEntryObj`. To be sure it will work everywhere inside that function use something like:

```
var _this = this;
```

And then use `_this` inside any event handlers.